# Cutting down on mod_rewrite rules

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have two rewrite rules in place: one for hosting server and one for my local test server (which uses dev-sk-... for its URLs).

'en/' is added if the site is accessed via a .co.uk domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.co.uk/en/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-sk-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://dev-sk-domain.co.uk/en/ [R=301,L]
```

Can these be merged into one rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to write this as

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [R=301,L]
```